# SOCKET communication through C++ on Win7 with other than English OS languages

Tags: c++, sockets, communication

I have a project where I communicate with the server through socket and is running for long period.(Source code below...) However on win 7 with languages as **Danish/Chinese** on some machines it gives me erorrs like: `a particular servelet doesn't exist`. Although the connection is created and message is sent but I receive back the message as an error.

Now I want to include `winsock2.h` with `Ws2_32.lib` and want to change `MAKEWORD(1,1)` to `MAKEWORD(2,2)`. How far it is safe for me to go with this change with a project which is running since a long period?

// I have included the basic sources here.

```
#include <winsock.h>
// with winsock32.lb

SOCKET sockRef = NULL;
struct sockaddr_in srvInfo;
struct hostent *netHostForName = NULL;

WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(1,1);
int nRet = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

netHostForName = gethostbyname(serverName);
memcpy((char *)&srvInfo.sin_addr, netHostForName->h_addr,
                netHostForName->h_length);
srvInfo.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
srvInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;

sockRef = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
connect(sockRef, (struct sockaddr *)&srvInfo,sizeof(srvInfo));

// Sending messages with
SockWrite(Socket, message, strlen(message), 0);

//Receiving messages with
recv(Socket, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), 0);

CLOSESOCKET(Socket);
WSACleanup();
```

Comment: How are you creating `message`? I'm guessing this is an encoding problem. If you are sending strings, make sure both sides use the same encoding, for example utf-8.

Answer (score 2):

its not the socket , its the data , use utf-8 encoded data as char stream.